# Pickle can't pickle an object with wrapped function

Tags: python, pickle, wrapper, python-decorators

I have a library function which I ran through a wrapper function to disable printing.

However, I need to somehow make that wrapped function not cause pickling errors. I get `AttributeError: Can't pickle local object 'mute.<locals>.wrapper'`

First bottom line of the stack `File "C:\Users\[...]\Python310\site-packages\neat\checkpoint.py", line [...], in save_checkpoint pickle.dump(data, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)`

I am only including my best guess which code is relevant, cause the whole code is quite big.

bu.py

```
def mute(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        import sys
        original_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = open(os.devnull, 'w')
        f(*args, **kwargs)
        sys.stdout.close()
        sys.stdout = original_stdout
    
    return wrapper
```

main.py

```
...
p = neat.Population(config)

reporter_to_add = neat.Checkpointer(1)
reporter_to_add.save_checkpoint = bu.mute(reporter_to_add.save_checkpoint)
p.add_reporter(reporter_to_add)

reporter_to_add = custom_reporters.FullPopulationCheckpointer(1)
reporter_to_add.save_checkpoint = bu.mute(reporter_to_add.save_checkpoint)
p.add_reporter(reporter_to_add)

p.run(gym.eval_genomes, 10)
...
```

neat.Checkpoint.py

```
class Checkpointer(BaseReporter):
    ...
    def save_checkpoint(self, config, population, species_set, generation):
        """ Save the current simulation state. """
        filename = '{0}{1}'.format(self.filename_prefix,generation)
        print("Saving checkpoint to {0}".format(filename))

        with gzip.open(filename, 'w', compresslevel=5) as f:
            data = (generation, config, population, species_set, random.getstate())
            pickle.dump(data, f, protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
```

I have tried putting a global wrapper in the mute() function, but that didn't work and also I don't know if I should have them global, cause there will be multiple save_checkpoint functions as you can see. They are different.

Everything works fine if the bu.mute() wrapper is not used.

Comment: Pickle never stores classes or functions, only the data on instances of classes, plus the information to later import the classes and functions again. If the data you are trying to pickle contains a nested function, then *that function can't be imported later on*, so pickling fails. That nested function can only be re-created by doing more than importing.

Comment: Ah, the `pickle` call is part of the `save_checkpoint()` method you wrapped. You could try removing the `mute` wrapper from the data you pass in to `f(...)`, but then you'll loose the wrappers when you unpickle the safepoints.

Comment: You could also try the [`dill` library](https://pypi.org/project/dill/) which extends pickle to add code object pickling (including nested functions).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks for the comments. What do you mean exactly with the second comment? What mute wrapper and data re you refering to exactly? You mean just before pickle is dumping, I remove the wrapper from the function? If so, how do I remove the wraper and get back the original function?

Comment: Yes, just before dumping, remove the wrappers. If you use the [`@functools.wraps`  decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps), then your wrapper will have a `__wrapped__` attribute pointing back to the original.